# Django: How to organize model structure, one-model or relations between few models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I have dilemma how to build my models structure. First of all I will explain my situation. I am selling goods on eBay basis on dropshipping, so when I have new order on ebay then I make order on my partner shop.

I would like create app where I can organize all orders from two platforms. I will use eBay API, PayPal API, PrestaShop API.

My question is: **How to plan structure of models?**

**One model with no relations:**

```
# eBay App
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sales_manager_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    shop_order_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # order ID from webshop
    shop_order_invoice = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # invoice num from webshop
```

**Few models with relations:**

```
# eBay App
class ebayOrder(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sales_manager_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

# shop app
class shopOrder(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    shop_order_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # order ID from webshop
    shop_order_invoice = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # invoice num from webshop
    ebay_order = models.ForeignKey(ebayOrder)
```

I must say that I have already created several applications in this project (I am generating ebay listings based on products in local db) so I will not create new app only for shopOrder needs.

**UPDATE:**

I presented only the basic version of my models. There will be more fields.

```
#eBay App
date, paid_date, amount, sales_manager_id, tracking_number, comment

#shop App
order_id, shop_order_id, invoice, products_amount, shipping_amount, shipping_date

#ebay App - customer_address model, shipping addres etc
order_id, nick, email, name, street1, street2, postcode, city, phone, state, country, company, vat, comment
```

Comment: why are you using ForeignKey ( ebay_order = models.ForeignKey(ebayOrder)). One ebayOrder may have multiple shopOrders ?

Comment: Yes. In situation when customer want to change his order.

Comment: In this situation, why dont you just update your model (so you ll have OneToOne relationship). Do you need to keep track of all changes, and assume that the last one is the most recent ?

Comment: Next situation may be I must send second package (for example parcel with missing items). So I have one order on eBay and few orders in shop. I want to use that relation. This is not the subject of my question. I only want to know: use simple model or few connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer one model without relationships.
It is better for performance reasons, because you can grab all your data with only one SQL query. Actually, using Fat models is one of best practices in django dev.
In your case, i am not sure if multiple entries of Order, may have the same date, paid, sales_manager_id fields. So every time a user updates his order, you create a new entry, copy the first 3 fields and fill the rest. If that is the case, then definitely break your model. It is bad practice to copy fields between entries in the same table.

Comment: Thank you, your opinion is helpfull. I updated my question, I added a few extra columns. So do you think should I join ebayOrder and shopOrder to one model?

Comment: Based on my answer, you should take the decision, because you know you app better and all the possible future extensions. Possibly, you think that a model with many fields is bad practice and thus you must cut it into smaller. This is not True.

Comment: Just I don't have experience with model building. Yes, that is my thinking :) Actually I am reading about antipattern. I think in future I would like make operations at orders, invoices etc. Ok I will start with fat model and I will implement only basic functionality and in the future I will thinking about upgrade structure.

Comment: A database with many fields is not a problem.
A problem is when you have many small models and you need many sql queries to grab an object (p.x. and Order)